# .Net Core 3.1 Imported WCF Reference ignores Enum values

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, .net-core

When I am adding the WCF reference from the WSDL in .Net Core 3.1 project, the enums lose their values.
In .Net 4.7.2 project everything is OK.

I have noticed that different serialization tools are used

"System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0"  -In .Net 4.7.2

"Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.0.2" - In .Net Core 3.1

How can I handle this issue?

WSDL:
[image]

.Net 4.7.2
[image]

.Net Core 3.1:
[image]

Comment: Looks like a bug in the tooling https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/4105

Comment: DavidG I saw this link. But there is no solution...

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem but did not succeed. I used "Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil, 2.0.2" to successfully generate the Enum value. I suspect that the service interface may cause this problem.

Comment: Ding Peng - Which IDE do you use? I work with VS2019. Doy you if I can reinstall Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil tool or configure VS to use maybe another one?

Comment: I also use VS2019, which may have nothing to do with the tool, or it may be related to the service interface.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this

```
   public enum Status
    {
        None = 0,
        TransferToUnderwriter = 998,
        Rejected = 999
    }
    public class Test
    {

        private Status _TransferToUnderwriter { get; set;  }
        public string TransferToUnderwriter
        {
            get {return _TransferToUnderwriter.ToString() ;}
            set {_TransferToUnderwriter = (Status)Enum.Parse(typeof(Status), value) ;} 
        }
    }
```